# Why doesn't the Coriolis force deflect incoming projectiles and rockets?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, projectile, coriolis-effect

The calculation shows that at a distance of 10 km, the deviation due to the action of the Coriolis force will be more than 8 m, and at a distance of 20 km already more than 30 m, which is quite significant, but no one takes this into account when shooting, does not introduce any corrections for the Coriolis force.
although, considering its influence, they must do it?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand.  Royal Navy (and presumably others) accounted for this (assuming Northern Hemisphere) in their firing solutions.

Answer (score 8):

> ... no one takes this into account when shooting ...

Yes, they do. [This page](https://thearmsguide.com/5329/external-ballistics-the-coriolis-effect-6-theory-section/) and [this page](https://www.thetruthaboutguns.com/coriolis-effect-for-beginners-extreme-long-range-shooting-for-beginners/) at target shooting sites describe the effect of the Coriolis force on long range shooting.